# 403 forbidden errors when pulling HTML with Python, but can view in web browser

Tags: nginx, python-requests

When using the requests library in Python to pull HTML of a given URL, eg. as follows:

```
import requests
temp = requests.get(URL)
HTML = temp.text
```

For some URL's it'll be forbidden by Nginx, returning only the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

However, for these URL's if I view them in any web browser, I can view the webpage without any 403 forbidden error.

A couple of example webpages where this is the case:

```
URL = http://socialmarketingwriting.com/complete-guide-successful-social-media-manager/
URL = https://rjmccollam.com/podcast/3/
```

Is there anything that can be done in these cases to avoid the 403 forbidden error?

Comment: some websites require some form of headers in order to work. I suspect a simple ```User-Agent``` header would fix your problem. Check out the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) or any other online resource for more info

Comment: Looks like that was the issue

Comment: @ZhouW does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

While using Python Requests without specifying the user-agent, uses its default user-agent (a bot-like one, i guess). This is blocked by many sites. To see that,go visit the `robots.txt` file of the domain, like:

```
www.google.com/robots.txt
```

Here is how you could use a User-Agent :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL='https://google.com/search?q=' + sear
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT} # adding the user agent
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser") # use this if you want to scrape the site
```